# How to filter a Stream[Future[A]]-like class by sub-type B<:A?

Tags: scala, type-erasure, type-parameter

I have this class that manage reception of a stream of asynchronous messages. It has type argument, say `A`, and I like to implement a function that filter those messages by type, say `B<:A`

But my first implementation is not working due to type erasure (see example below). Is there a good way to so?

Here is a simplified example of my problem:

```
package test.filterByType

import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.Future

trait MessageStream[A]{ self =>

  def next(): Future[A]

  def filter[B<:A]: MessageStream[B] = new MessageStream[B]{
    def next(): Future[B] = self.next.flatMap{
      case b: B => Future.successful(b)
      case _    => next()
      }
  }
}

case class MessageStreamImpl[A](msg: IndexedSeq[A]) extends MessageStream[A]{
  private var index = 0
  def next() = {
    index += 1
    Future.successful(msg(index-1))
  }
}

object Main{
  trait A
  case class B(i: Int) extends A
  case class C(i: Int) extends A

  def main(args: Array[String]){
    val msg: IndexedSeq[A] = (1 to 10).map{ i => if(i%2==0) B(i) else C(i) }
    val streamOfA = MessageStreamImpl(msg)
    val streamOfB = streamOfA.filter[B]

    val b: B = Await.result(streamOfB.next(), 1 second)
  }
}
```

At compilation, I get `warning: abstract type pattern B is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure`, and indeed the code does not work. If I execute Main, I get the error:
`lang.ClassCastException: test.filterByType.Main$C cannot be cast to test.filterByType.Main$B`

Which happens because it does not filter out the first list item `C(1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This small adjustment does the trick

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
def filter[B<:A](implicit C: ClassTag[B]): MessageStream[B] = new MessageStream[B]{
    def next(): Future[B] = self.next.flatMap{
        case b: B => Future.successful(b)
        case _    => next()
    }
}
```

Comment: I've seen this `ClassTag` thing before. Could you explain a little why this make it work?

Comment: A `ClassTag[T]` stores the erased class of a given type `T`. So in essence it's made to solve the problem you where facing.

Answer (score 0):

I've found an alternative that works:

```
def collect[B<:A](f: PartialFunction[A,B]) = new MessageStream[B] {
  override def next(): Future[B] = self.next().flatMap { m =>
    if (f.isDefinedAt(m)) Future.successful(f(m))
    else next()
  }
}
```